# Storing small files in cassandra

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, thrift, hector

Are there examples of either an API(Thrift or Hector) or some commands in cassandra-cli that explains how to store small(few hundred KBs) files in Cassandra.

I've tried googling but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonable to put values of that size in a single column; a single column value can be up to 2 GiB in size. The main reason to keep columns smaller is that the whole value will be read into memory when used, so it's generally better to keep them under a few MB.